# Some simple questions about "generalized linear model"

Tags: generalized-linear-model, references

I have two simple questions about generalized linear models (GLMs) which for some reason I could not find a good reference for:

1. What is the form of the hypothesis/predictor for generalized linear model? i.e., some function $f: x \mapsto \widehat{y}$, $\widehat{y}$ is the prediction of the label of $x$
2. What is the usual loss function/in-sample error associated with training a GLM?

Comment: For your 1., what exactly are you asking about? You can have null hypotheses about specific parameters, but that does not seem to be what you are asking about. It looks like you wonder about a *point prediction*, which is different from a *predictor* (which is a different term for what you could also call a *regressor*, i.e., a column in the design matrix).

Comment: I think by *hypothesis* the OP doesn't mean to refer to a hypothesis test, but a candidate model that approximates a target function, per machine-learning usage. They (the people that introduced ML terms) seem to have a habit (given the frequency, one might even start to suspect deliberate) of choosing terms that conflict with long pre-existing terms in statistics.

Comment: @Fraïssé The wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model explains the components of a GLM (i) linear predictor, (ii) link function relating linear predictor to mean, (iii) conditional distribution of the response. Since estimation is based on maximizing likelihood, one way to look at the loss function is the negative of twice the log likelihood, but it's usually recast in terms of the deviance

Comment: There's plenty of questions on site relating to the components of GLMs.